# What kind of tree it is? How to solve the problem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I have a tree with following configuration:

`n` is the number of different vertices `v` ($0 \lt v \le n$). Each vertice `v` have value `Val(v)`. Same vertex will have same value. Each vertex `vi` always have a set of branch all vertex `v` $\le$ `vi`. The tree have deep `d` which is the number of step from root to every leaf.

The tree have cost C which is total all values in all leaf. Please look at [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_KQ8JA8_X0TdXk0RUJSSEZRb2s/view?usp=sharing) and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_QH2qxODqKR2tzTERqckdqR0U/view?usp=sharing) for example. When we have `n`, set of `vi`, and `d` how to get C.

Comment: Please feel free to edit for better explained. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that at each depth $1 < d \leq n$ and counting sequence $c_{n,d}$, where $c_{n,d}$ represents the number of the $v_n$s we have at depth $d$, we have

$$ c_n = 1, 1, 1,  \ldots \\ c_{n-1} = 1,2,3, \ldots \\ c_{n-2} = 1,3,6, \ldots \\ c_1 = 1, \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} c_{n-k,1}, \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} c_{n-k,2}, \ldots . $$

Take a look at these numbers carfully.

They are in fact, the diagonal columns of [pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Thus, we have that $c_{k,d} =  {d - 1 \choose n - k}$ and then the sum we are looking for is $$\sum_{k = 1}^n {d - 1 \choose n - k} Val(v_k).$$

Comment: the probem need variable d, look at the example, d = 2, so there are 6 leaves. How about d=3 (10 leaves)?

Comment: @smftr I now understand the question.

Comment: @smftr Is that better?

Comment: I think so, i will verify